# Phpunit obscure error logging

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using Phpunit 3.7, and I've been encountering following error logs when I run my tests through the command line:

```
Running TestSuite tests
PHPUnit 3.7.25 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from phpunit.xml

..................E<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Unsupported operand types</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

There is no log trace or anything that would help me nail down where the error actually is... how do I get phpunit to log this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run the PHPUnit test in debug mode:

```
phpunit --debug
```

This will write the name of each executed test class and method in front of the test result and give you a way to find out which test fails and emits that SOAP XML failure.